# MySQL: is this possible to do?

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to accomplish something, but I'm a bit of a noob, and don't know if this can be done in one query.

I have two tables that look like this:

**table 1:**

```
link_id    target_country
-------------------------
1          5
2          3
```

**table 2:**

```
id_country   country
-------------------------
5            Belgium
5            Russia
2            USA
```

So, from the data above, **link_id 1** has a **target_country of 5**, which means that this link belongs to **Belgium** and **Russia** (since **id_country 5** in **table 2** is linked to these countries)

My idea is that after passing several **link_ids** to a mysql query, I can obtain something like:

- Belgium => 1 (since **link_id is 1** for the Belgium link)
- Russia => 1 (This **link_id 1** also belongs to Russia)
- USA => 2

How can I do so with one query and only by passing **link_ids**? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT country, link_id
FROM table_2
INNER JOIN table_1
ON table_2.id_country = table_1.target_country
WHERE table_1.link_id IN (1, 2);
```

This is a standard [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT link_id, country
FROM table1 links
    INNER JOIN table2 countries ON links.target_country = countries.id_country
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    table2.country 
FROM 
    table1, 
    table2 
WHERE
    table2.country_id = table1.target_country AND
    table1.target_country = 5;
```

make sure that you actually do have a primary index on table2 - the country_id cannot be a primary index if it is not unique!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.country, t1.link_id 
FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2 
WHERE t1.target_country = t2.id_country
```